# Invalid transaction signature on sending transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, signature, golang, clients

Hello guys I'm having a "Invalid transaction signature." error. Can't get pass this one. Am I missing something?

```
client, err := ethclient.Dial("path/to/geth.ipc")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
ks := keystore.NewKeyStore("path/to/keystore", keystore.StandardScryptN, keystore.StandardScryptP)

to := common.HexToAddress("0x999b010976f0fb4d4e43646bc6c8fbd9ea7f5323")
from := common.HexToAddress("0x53a8368b7f6d140cdb5e0bf6dce0cbe9e6934430")
data := []byte("Lorem ipsum")
value := big.NewInt(10000000000000000)

gasPrice, err := client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    return err
}

msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
    From:     from,
    To:       &to,
    GasPrice: gasPrice,
    Value:    value,
    Data:     data,
}
gasLimit, err := client.EstimateGas(context.Background(), msg)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

nonce, err := client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), from)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

newTx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, to, value, gasLimit, gasPrice, data)
networkID, err := client.NetworkID(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    return err
}

signedTx, err := ks.SignTxWithPassphrase(accounts.Account{Address: from}, "secret", newTx, networkID)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if err := client.SendTransaction(context.Background(), signedTx); err != nil {
    return err // Error triggered here
}
```

Comment: please confirm that your account keystore json file exists in the `"path/to/keystore"` path under `--datadir` of the node you're connecting to

Comment: Yes it exists the password, network ID is also correct when I dump the values.

Comment: which geth version are you using, I cannot find `"Invalid transaction signature."` in the latest geth codebase.

Comment: I'm using `Geth
Version: 1.8.14-unstable
Git Commit: 99e1a5e0fb6f238319042dd2c4c8468dc786a4b7` build from source

Comment: okay, let me try to run on my local to see what's happen

Answer (score 0):

I used your source code and able to run on my local without any problem. I put the code into github, please check it out.

https://github.com/hadv/ipc-client

tnx was submitted and mined successfully by the node.

```
INFO [08-31|16:58:32.050] Setting new local account                address=0xE348073d55AdE0Ef0E5696bA51D5565003233D0C
INFO [08-31|16:58:32.051] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0xff173c546e3bbd345013348c85e8921ccf7e9aed23e74af044843d5e54e04754 recipient=0xD5089c1Fdf8ceBF58c6bBb50a86C1c55893634b8
```

It seems that you make somethings wrong somewhere in node config!